# sendmail for local network / home networking

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, sendmail

All the `sendmail` configuration I found so far are either allow connections from local host (`127.0.0.1`) or anywhere (`0.0.0.0`). How to configure `sendmail` to allow connections from local network (`192.168.x.x`) instead?

I've found many `sendmail` configuration articles
http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-Sendmail
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4541
http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administrations/sendmail-server.html
but none discuss about this.

Is it possible? Thx.

Comment: Do you really want to use Sendmail? Postfix is *much* easier to configure.

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `iptables` to block all traffic to Sendmail except for 192.168.x.x?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sendmail-is-only-accepting-connections-from.html does this help?

Comment: Thanks @DanielCheung, I've lost my home networking environment, thus I can't verify it, but I can accept yours as the answer.